# Get ID token for previously granted client

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak

I'm trying to implement a ChatOps solution. For this I've setup a Keycloak server that validates users against our Active Directory server.

I've configured a RocketChat server that allows users to login with Keycloak by configuring an custom oauth solution (keycloak).
Everything works fine. The user logs in and gives access to the configured client and can start talking to our ChatOps bot.

What I now want is to call an external API (also in my control) from the bot on behalf of the user giving the commando. The only information about the user that I have in the chatbot is the username from keycloak. But I assume this should be enough as the user has approved the client (rocketchat/bot, sharing the same client-id and secret) before.

Is it possible to get a new token for the user by just his username with the precondition that the user has granted access for the client before?